# Toggle between languages in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder, internationalization

I'm making a tourist map for out municipality in ArcGIS Online. I would like to have it in 2 Languages (English and Norwegian). I have two separate layers for each Language Version.

Does anyone know if it is possible in ArcGIS online to set two buttons that will toggle between 2 Languages?

The way I have it now, is that I have set 2 separate widgets, one for English Version and one for Norwegian Version. The problem is, it doesn't really toggle between Languages. I still have to go in and switch off one layer before switching on the other.

Has anyone tried this before?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with ArcGIS Online to embed an app within an app.

In short:

1) Create a web app in each of the two languages

2) Make those apps public, and copy the embed code from the "share" button

3) Create a separate story map with two tabs

4) In each tab, select the option to embed a web page

5) Embed each of the two language apps in separate tabs.

This might give more guidance: https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2016/05/29/embed-story-map-in-story-map/